# How do I get "Others" working with ASP.NET SignalR?

Tags: signalr

I'm trying to write a SignalR hub that doesn't ping messages back to the caller. I've implemented a handler called "BatteryChanged" which simply calls "onBatteryChanged" in all connected clients. My understanding is that I should use `Others` to filter out the caller:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void BatteryChanged(double level)
    {
        Clients.Others.onBatteryChanged(level);
    }
}
```

My one-and-only client (for this test at least) is a WPF application that initializes the connection like so:

```
Connection = new HubConnection(ServerURI);
HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("myHub");

// set up SignalR handlers
HubProxy.On<double>("onBatteryChanged", (battery) =>
{
    // do something with the message here
});
```

Once the connection has been established my WPF client invokes the method on the hub:

```
this.HubProxy.Invoke("BatteryChanged", level);
```

For some reason this doesn't work, the message arrives on the hub and gets dispatched out to Clients.Others but the onBatteryChanged handler in the calling client gets called as well.

Can anyone tell me how to get SignalR to filter the message properly?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that stumbles across this in future the problem is apparently one of nomenclature. Specifically, my hub function contains a method called "BatteryChanged" which invokes a method called "onBatteryChanged" in the clients. It would appear that something is going on internally in SignalR where they prefix the "BatteryChanged" method with "on" and this creates a naming conflict. Simply changing the name of my "onBatteryChanged" function to "handleBatteryChanged" resolved the issue.